# label doesn't appear in java gui

Tags: java, label

i am new in java so i am sorry if this question is easy.I am have issues with using layer.

```
public class LoginPage extends JFrame {

private JButton loginBtn = new JButton("Login");
private JLabel nameLbl = new JLabel("UserName: ");

public LoginPage(){

    this.setTitle("Licence Management Software");
    this.setSize(640 , 480);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    loginBtn.setBounds(10,20,100,40);


    this.add(loginBtn);
    this.add(nameLbl);

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new LoginPage();
}
}
```

Button is running without a problem but label does not appear.Thank you for your help.I am using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

#### Some points.

- Call `this.setVisible(true);` in the end after adding all the component.
- Don't use `null` layout. there are lots of layout mangers, use any one that suits as per your need.

  [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
- Don't use `setSize()` method, just leave it for layout manager to set the size and position as per component's preferred dimension. Call `JFrame#pack()` to fit all the components in the frame.

Comment: i tried it but it didnt change anything but thank you for your help

Comment: since you are using null layout so you have set setBounds of the label.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code try this one

```
public class LoginPage extends JFrame {

private JButton loginBtn = new JButton("Login");
private JLabel nameLbl = new JLabel("UserName: ");
private Container container;

public LoginPage(){

container=this.getContentPane();
this.setTitle("Licence Management Software");
this.setSize(640 , 480);
this.setLayout(null);
this.setVisible(true);
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
loginBtn.setBounds(10,20,100,40);


container.add(loginBtn);
container.add(nameLbl);
this.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
new LoginPage();
}
}
```

Hope this helps you.